# Can I bind a key to give my pet a potion?

Tags: torchlight

In torchlight I know how to feed my pet a potion <kbd>Shift</kbd>+*Right Click* and how to bind an action to a number key, but how can bind giving a potion *to my pet* to an action key (ie: 2).

Comment: Side note, fish are another cheap way to heal your pet.  Yes it transforms into something but it will also have its mana and hp restored to full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give a potion to the pet by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press the shortcut of the potion. So if your health potion is on <kbd>2</kbd>, you would press <kbd>Shift</kbd> & <kbd>2</kbd>